# HTML: image using 2 style attributes in one element

Tags: html

**What I want:** 
My image to be resized and centred.

**What's happening:**
The image is resized, but not centred

**My code:**

```
< img style="text-align:center;width:204px;height:204px;" src="image.jpeg" >
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I prevent this happening with other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `text-align: center;` should be placed on the parent element, not itself.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img style="width: 204px; height: 204px;" src="image.jpeg">
</div>
```

Comment: @RelativelyMediocre No problem! If it worked, please mark this answer as 'accepted' by pressing the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Will do as soon as it lets me :)

Comment: Thanks! Good luck on your project!